# Is the Chinese Registry really this obliging?

Tags: domain-registration

> Dear Manager,
>
> Hope you everything goes well. We have not heard from you. As
> mentioned in my previous email, anybody can register the China domain
> names(###.cn,
> ###.com.cn, ###.net.cn, ###.org.cn) and internet keyword because your company haven't registered this name as China domain name and internet
> keyword on the internet You must know domain name and internet keyword
> based on the international principle are opened to company as well as
> individual. Also, we have suggested they should choose another name bu
> they persist in this name. In this situation, we have told you have
> priority right to register China domain name and internet keyword
> during our dispute period. Them dispute period is about to come to an
> end soon. After that, it will result in these CN domains and keyword
> being available to the other party. Could you please tell us if your
> company register these China domain names and internet keywords to
> prevent others from using them?
>
> China Registry (Head Office)

All URLs in this are valid. But, I am regarding this as a scam. Is there any chance this is a real thing?

Comment: Ask directly your registrar for help. But from the look of it it is the usual very very old scam of "please hurry to register X because someone is just trying to and you should have priority".

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Actually, this is a very old scam (harking back to 2010)

Comment: Yes, it is a very old one, as I said in previous comment, and for multiple registries, not just the "China" one. The simple bad phrasing in multiple places would be ground for immediate deletion in my eyes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right to treat it as a scam - its a very old one at that.  It does not come from an official registry, and its looking to coerce you into purchasing a domain name you don't need.

Google "China Registry Scam" and you will get a lot of links about this.  Here is a Guardian link covering off this scam - https://www.theguardian.com/technology/askjack/2015/may/05/how-does-a-domain-name-scam-work which links to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_scams#Fake_trademark_protection and a number of other pages which are so old as to have been deleted.